# Probability of exactly n customers arrive between consecutive buses

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Customers arrive at a bus stop according to a Poisson process with rate $3$ per hour. Buses arrive at the stop according to a Poisson process with rate $1.5$ per hour.

(a) What is the probability that exactly $n$ customers arrive between consecutive buses?

(b) Assume each bus can hold at most $2$ customers. Also assume at most $4$ people wait for the bus (subsequent customers are turned away). Model this process as a continuous-time Markov chain. Give the transition-rate matrix Q.

**My attempted solution** Part (a) was solved thanks to Did's help!

(b) Let $X(t) =$ # of people at the stop at time $t$. Then $X(t) = 0,1,2,3,4$ (since subsequent customers are turned away). Thus, the transition rate matrix is $$Q =\pmatrix{-3 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1.5 & -4.5 & 3 & 0 & 0\\ 1.5 & 0 & -4.5 & 3 & 0\\ 0 & 1.5 & 0 & -4.5 & 3\\ 0 & 0 & 1.5 & 0 & -1.5}$$

Comment: Nobody wants to help me with this problem?? I'm stuck seriously :(

Comment: Calling $T$ the time between two consecutive buses and $N$ the number of customers arriving in this time interval, $$P(N=n\mid T=t)=e^{-at}\frac{(at)^n}{n!}$$ with $a=3$. Furthermore, $T$ is exponential with parameter $b=1.5$ hence $$P(N=n)=\int_0^\infty P(N=n)\mid T=t)be^{-bt}dt=ba^n\int_0^\infty e^{-(a+b)t}\frac{t^n}{n!}dt=\frac{ba^n}{(a+b)^{n+1}}=\frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}}$$

Comment: @Did: great solution!! I'm so dumb:(( But could you help with part (b) as well? I think I could define the state = # of customers waiting for the bus (I'm not so sure if this is the right way though). So we should have 5 states. But calculating the probability between different states is quite difficult for me:(

Comment: This is beginning to sound awfully like "do my homework for me asap plz"... How come you have no idea where to start?

Comment: @Did: I finally got it Sir. My apology for my lack of patience, but I'm studying for my incoming qualifying exam, and I know that these questions are not that difficult for you or some people here (I'm just not one of you guys...)